# Assign specific role per authentication provider in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I have several authentication providers configured in GeoServer (2.24).

Can I assign a specific role to users depending on the provider they were logged in with?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can using the built in providers.

An alternative way is to create your own authentication proxy that passes on the user name and roles in http headers and use header authentication in Geoserver. When using header authentication Geoserver believes anything that comes in the roles header and it is easy to add an extra role depending on how the user was authenticated in your proxy.

The drawback is obviously that you can't make use of any of the built in mechanisms in Geoserver and have to implement them yourself in your proxy. You also need to implement the user-role mapping. How much work it is depends on which types of authentication you have and how you store your user-role mapping.

Comment: My research led me to the same conclusion and your suggestions are useful. Thanks! :)